# Can Pandas to_excel support hyperlink style now?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I can't find an answer (or one I know how to implement) when it comes to using the excel "hyperlink" style for a column when exporting using pd.to_excel.

I can find plenty of (OLD) answers on using xlsxwriter or openpyxl. But none using the current pandas functionality.

I think it might be possible now with the updates to the .style function? But I don't know how to implement the CSS2.2 rules to emulate the hyperlink style.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':1, 'link':['=HYPERLINK("http://www.someurl.com", "some website")']})
df.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

The desired output is for the link column, to be the standard blue underlined text that then turns purple once you have clicked the link.

Is there a way to use the built in excel styling? Or would you have to pass various css properties througha dictionary using .style?

Comment: What's wrong with using xlsxwriter or openpyxl? They're what pandas is using under the hood anyway.

Comment: I was just hoping that there was a cleaner way. to apply the formatting to an entire column of urls.

Comment: ... and look, you get an answer from the author of xlsxwriter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it using xlsxwriter as the Excel engine:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                   'link':['=HYPERLINK("http://www.python.org", "some website")',
                           '=HYPERLINK("http://www.python.org", "some website")']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')


# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the default URL format.
url_format = workbook.get_default_url_format()

# Apply it to the appropriate column, and widen the column.
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 40, url_format)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Output, note that the second link has been clicked and is a different color:

[image]

Note, it would be preferable to use the xlsxwriter [worksheet.write_url()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url) method since that will look like a native Excel url to the end user and also doesn't need the above trick of getting and applying the url format. However, that method can't be used directly from a pandas dataframe (unlike the formula) so you would need to iterate through the link column of the dataframe and overwrite the formulas programatically with actual links.

Something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2],
                   'link':['=HYPERLINK("http://www.python.org", "some website")',
                           '=HYPERLINK("http://www.python.org", "some website")']})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test2.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the worksheet handle.
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Widen the colum for clarity
worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 40)

# Overwrite the urls
worksheet.write_url(1, 2, "http://www.python.org", None, "some website")
worksheet.write_url(2, 2, "http://www.python.org", None, "some website")

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to set vertical alignment of a hyperlink to the top of a cell with a set_column() statement, without having to overwrite the URLs with write_url()? An example is contained in this example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73493944). Thank you.

Comment: If writer.save() doesn't work, use writer.close() instead as the former is a deprecated API.