# Pandas convert raw hyperlink to clickable display in excel file

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, list

I have a pandas dataframe with the below data

```
data = {'product_id': [11,11,11,11],
        'rec_prod_id':[12,13,14,15],
        'product_URL': ['www.example.com','www.example4.com','www.example3.com','www.example2.com']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

My objective is to

1. group the product_id and perform aggregation - nunique and list
2. convert the product_id as clickable for each rec_prod_id (which will take me to the respective webpage) when I export the dataframe to excel file

So, I tried the below by referring the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820069/add-hyperlink-to-excel-sheet-created-by-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-method)

```
def create_hyperlink(row):
    return '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'.format(row['product_id'], row['product_URL'])
data['product_hyperlinks'] = data.apply(create_hyperlink, axis=1)
data.groupby('product_id').agg{('# of recs'=product_id:nunique,product_links:list)}
```

But the above results in unexpected and incorrect output (I get raw urls like below in the output) when I export the excel file

[image]

**But I expect my output to be like below**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HYPERLINK` function in your function and then set clickable urls:

```
data = {'product_id': [11, 22, 31, 45],
        'product_URL': ['https://www.google.com','https://www.google.com',
                        'https://www.google.com','https://www.google.com']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

def create_hyperlink(row):
    return '=HYPERLINK("{1}", "{0}")'.format(row['product_id'], row['product_URL'])

data['product_hyperlinks'] = data.apply(create_hyperlink, axis=1)

#https://stackoverflow.com/a/73489111/2901002
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
data.to_excel(writer, index=False)
    
# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Get the default URL format.
url_format = workbook.get_default_url_format()

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

[image: pic]

For HMTL use your solution (swap {0} and {1}) and add `escape=False` to [`DataFrame.to_html`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html):

```
def create_hyperlink(row):
    return '<a href="{1}">{0}</a>'.format(row['product_id'], row['product_URL'])


data['product_hyperlinks'] = data.apply(create_hyperlink, axis=1)


data.to_html('file.html', index=False, escape=False)
```

EDIT: Alternative solution for write links to excel in loop:

```
data = {'product_id': [11, 22, 31, 45],
        'product_URL': ['https://www.google.com','https://www.google.com',
                        'https://www.google.com','https://www.google.com']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
data.to_excel(writer, index=False)


# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

data['product_hyperlinks'] = ""

pos = data.columns.get_loc('product_hyperlinks')

for i, (name, link) in enumerate(zip(data['product_id'], data['product_URL'])):
    worksheet.write_url(i+1, pos, link, None, str(name))

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.close()
```

Comment: Oh great. will this be applicable to html object as well? Meaning, if I do df.to_html(), will it automatically show them as hyperlinks as well? or this works only for excel option?

Comment: @TheGreat - I have to test it.

Comment: @TheGreat - added solution to answer.

Comment: @TheGreat - I add `https` to test data, can you test?

Comment: @TheGreat - What is your pandas version? what is your excel version?

Comment: I test it in `pandas: 2.0.3` and in `excel 2016`

Comment: I think I identified the issue is because of groupby and agg. can you check my update sample data and expected output? need to have one hyperlink for each recommended product id

Comment: when I aggregate the product_hyperlinks column as list, it doesn't display the product ids. It shows the raw `HYPERLINK`

Comment: @TheGreat - yes, it is formula, so cannot aggregate

Comment: do you know it is possible to store each recommended product_id number as excel shape first and then insert hyperlink for each shape? https://www.automateexcel.com/how-to/multiple-hyperlinks-one-cell/

Comment: @TheGreat - Unfortunately not, Excel is not my good friend